# Ajax call to flask to return mysql query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to populate a drop-down list in my HTML. I am making an AJAX from my `app.js` call to my flask app `app.py`. I am trying to populate the data when the page first loads up and calling the AJAX in `$(document).ready` Like this:

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://myserver:5000/query",
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("This is the returned data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Here is the error res: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
});
```

When I refresh the page I do see my flask server successfully query the correct database and I do see the correct return. However, in my `app.js` side I get an empty list.

I see this in my flask server output:

```
((1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2'))
```

However, in my AJAX console, the return data is just `[]`.

Here is my flask `app.py`:

```
@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def query():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from names")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    return jsonify(cursor.fetchall())
```

I suspect that document ready might be running the ajax call BEFORE flask gets the data back.

So how can I get the data to populate when the flask query return is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `cursor.fetchall()`, it *fetches* all results from the cursor, leaving it empty. To make your code work, you should store result in some variable:

```
@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def query():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from names")
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    print(res)
    return jsonify(res)
```

This should work as you expected.

Comment: That worked! :) Quick question, do you think it's ideal to query on page refresh? Or does it make more sense to do it when the user selects the drop-down and populate it there? I'm trying to think in terms of performance if querying on page refresh would degrade the performance and speed of the webpage. I know this is more of a personal design problem, but you might have more experience on this, so I figured I ask you.

Comment: Depend on situation. If user will modify query somehow, then it is better to update the results with ajax calls. If query is the same all the time, it is better to do it on get request, probably, with some caching.

Comment: The query will be the same all the time. When you mean get request you mean doing an ajax get request and doing it on `$(document).ready` when the page loads ?

Comment: Yes, probably it is the best option. Also, if you are writing a new project, then give a try to https://vuejs.org instead of jquery.